# Problema Duplicidad de check en listview android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

Buenos días

Tengo un problema con un listview... que lleno desde un webservices, y en cada item que me pinta hay un checkbox el cual al dar click me debe de activar el edittex de ese item.. el problema es que si le doy click al primer check del primer item, y recorro hacia abajo mi scroll veo que me duplica ese check en otro item que no debe de estar, dejo codigo de mi techwacher  y de mi adaptador.

Codigo Techwatcher

```
private class TB_Abono_Watcher implements TextWatcher {


        Button pagar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pago);
        private View view;

        private TB_Abono_Watcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            final CXCPDetalle o_CXCP_Detalle = (CXCPDetalle) ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).getTag();

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
            if (settings.getInt("ONControlConexion", 0) == 0) {
                if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getViewChanged() == false) {

                    o_CXCP_Detalle.TotalAplicado = ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());

                    final Double Total = _TotalAplicado();

                    DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(Total));


                    ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setEnabled(true);
                    ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putString("ONControlCheck", String.valueOf(isChecked));
                            editor.commit();

                            o_CXCP_Detalle.setStatusCheck(String.valueOf(isChecked));


                            if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getStatusCheck() == "true") {

                                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                                ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(true);


                            } else {

                                Double TotalAplicado = Total;
                                DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                                ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
                                ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(false);
                                TotalAplicado = _TotalAplicado();
                                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(TotalAplicado));
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getStatusCheck() == "true") {
                        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(true);

                    } else {
                        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    //Validacion que no te deje hacer un abono Mayo al saldo vencido
                    if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getSaldo() < o_CXCP_Detalle.TotalAplicado) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes Aplicar un Abono Mayor al SaldoVencido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");

                    }


                }
```

Codigo Adapartador

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CXCPDetalle> {

        private Detalle_Cliente dataSet;
        Context mContext;
        boolean[] checkBoxState;

        // View lookup cache
        public class ViewHolder {

            public TextView txfecha = null;
            public TextView txfolio = null;
            public TextView txtotal = null;
            public TextView txttotal = null;
            public TextView vencido = null;
            public TextView parcialidad = null;
            public TextView pagoforma = null;
            public TextView ultimocobroob = null;
            public CheckBox checkBox = null;
            public EditText cantidad;


        }

        public CustomAdapter(Detalle_Cliente data, ArrayList context) {
            super(data, R.layout.row_detalle, context);
            this.dataSet = data;

        }

        private int lastPosition = -1;



        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the data item for this position
            final CXCPDetalle O_CXCPDetalle = getItem(position);
           // final ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

            final View result;

            if (convertView == null) {

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
               // ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));
                ((EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));


                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_CXCPDetalle);
                if (O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado != 0) {
                    ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText(String.valueOf(O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado));


                } else {
                    ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
                }



                viewHolder.txfecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
                viewHolder.txfolio = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio);
                viewHolder.txtotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);
                viewHolder.txttotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
                viewHolder.vencido = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido);
                viewHolder.parcialidad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parcialidad);
                viewHolder.pagoforma = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagoforma);
                viewHolder.ultimocobroob = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.UltimoCobroObservacion);
                viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(new Integer(position));




                result = convertView;

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                result = convertView;
               // viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            }


            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            viewHolder.checkBox.setFocusable(false);
            viewHolder.txfecha.setText(dateFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getFecha()));
            viewHolder.txfolio.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getFolio());
            viewHolder.txtotal.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal()));
            viewHolder.txttotal.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo()));
            viewHolder.vencido.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldoVencido()));
            viewHolder.parcialidad.setText((numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidadTotal()) + " - " + O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidad()));
            viewHolder.pagoforma.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getPagoCondicionDescripcion());
            viewHolder.ultimocobroob.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getUltimoCobroObservacion());
            viewHolder.checkBox.setEnabled(true);

            double Abono = 0.00;
            Abono = O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal() - O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo();
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagado)).setText(numberFormat.format(Abono));

            // Return the completed view to render on screen
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: según tengo entendido, es un problema de los listview, que para ahorrar memoria guardan el estado de los primeros y abajo no los actualiza bien.

Comment: si eso me imagine usa como un cache, pero como se soluciona? tu sabes como?

Comment: no estoy seguro, creo que hay que ir validandolos siempre http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840040/android-listview-adapter-checkbox-refreshing o cambiar el metodo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Mira este ejemplo, te puede ayudar: http://www.dipler.org/2011/02/solucionando-el-problema-de-los-listview-con-checkbox-en-android/